# Find if IP Address is in use

Tags: networking, ip-address

I'm trying to find if an IP address is in use. I don't want to rely on ping, as most of our hosts have ICMP echo and reply turned off.

I'm looking for something that mimics window's "IP Address Conflict" detection. (How does this mechanism do it?)

Comment: Windows does it by spamming ARP requests which cannot reach an outside network.

Comment: arping. google it.

Answer (score 3):

here is an arping program that works in cygwin: http://www.habets.pp.se/synscan/programs.php?prog=arping

i used this one myself.